# Panda Series Insert Error Missing Positional Argument and Does Not Match Index Length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that I am attempting to prepend a value to, but I am uncertain of  the best approach to doing just that. I have read that `.insert()` is the best method, but after trying two different variations of the method I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried

```
df_full_modified = df_full['date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc'].insert(0, ['date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc'])
```

which returns

```
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

and also tried adding in a value for the `columns` parameter

```
df_full_modified = df_full['date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc'].insert(0, ['date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc'], ['date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc'])
```

which returns

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Am I missing something with trying to map an array to the `insert()` method?

Here is the format of the data frame `df_full`:

```
[['2018-01-01', '72', 2.43], ['2018-01-02', '232', 2.8], ['2018-01-03', '255', 2.6], ...
```

and I am trying to prepend `['date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc']` to make it

```
[['date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc'], ['2018-01-01', '72', 2.43], ['2018-01-02', '232', 2.8], ['2018-01-03', '255', 2.6], ...
```

Comment: `'date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc'` are already column names right?

Comment: @d_kennetz That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you already have a df like this:

```
          date  b_clicks  b_cpc
0  2018-01-01'        72   2.43
1  2018-01-02'       232   2.80
2  2018-01-03'       255   2.60
```

And you want to insert a row to the top. df.insert inserts a column at a specified position, not a row. It looks like you understand that you can do this with a list, so you can just do your same operation by creating a new list with the words you have specified, and just concat the df you already have to the new list:

```
data = []
data.insert(0, {'date': 'date', 'b_clicks': 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc': 'b_cpc'})

df_full_modified = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data), df], ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
>>> df_full_modified
   b_clicks  b_cpc         date
0  b_clicks  b_cpc         date
1        72   2.43  2018-01-01'
2       232    2.8  2018-01-02'
3       255    2.6  2018-01-03'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your initial standpoint correctly, then the provided lists are stored in a pandas Series, like:

```
a = pd.Series([['2018-01-01', '72', 2.43], ['2018-01-02', '232', 2.8], ['2018-01-03', '255', 2.6]])
```

If yes, then you could simply create a Series for the `['date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc']` variable, like:

```
b = pd.Series({['date', 'b_clicks', 'b_cpc']])
```

and finally append `b` with `a`:

```
b = b.append(a)
```

However with this approach you will have to 0 indecies at the beginning of the series. I do not know if it bothers you.